# How to change the link of a BITLY link

Tags: email, hyperlink

I would like to create a bit.ly link with a temporary link in it. Once my client has sent me the final link, all I want to be able to do is go into Bit.ly and change the link there.

Reason I say this is because I have to send off Outlook templates NOW to the client and they needs to have the links in the template. Since they have no idea on how to change the link themselves, I would like to be able to just change the Bit.ly link once they send me the final link that the Bit.ly link needs to point to.

Does Bit.ly do this or is there something similar that can?

Seems they don't from this post:
http://bit.ly/pages/help#i_1_1

So now I need another solution please?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 2):

Is the link pointing to something you are hosting/controlling?  You could point it to a page which does nothing more than redirect.  Then when you need the link to go somewhere else, you just change the redirect on the page you control.  From the user's perspective there would be no difference.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me David. I would do this but I am in South Africa and the client is in Canada, so I have no idea what time they are going to send that link through. I need to send some instructions to them on how to change something like a bitly link so they can do that themselves. It should be super simple as they are not tech savvy peeps :)

Comment: @Sixfoot Studio, well you would have to create that ability.  The page that re-directs (the link you create and send them) accesses a database or flat file to determine where to send the browser.  Another page allows your client to update that database or flat file to change the location.

Comment: Thanks Fosco, I am going to so that!

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are a programmer, you can easily create a linking service yourself.

Just create a page, that spits out a 301 header. When you want it to change edit the code. Get fancy by putting it all in a database with a nice UI. Really it isn't that hard.

Comment: Thanks Byron. I will do that when I have more time but I am 2 minutes away from bed and need a quick solution :)